# Need to install SL on Mavericks external drive

Tags: macos, external-disk

I have a 2012 iMac 21" with the latest Mavericks.  I also have a need for a bootable Snow Leopard external drive so I can run Boot Camp with XP.  I purchased a Snow Leopard Retail install disk only to find the iMac refuses to boot from it and instead I get a blue screen with Black insert showing unix style error messages.  Sorry, but unable to capture these.

I have no doubt I am missing something here, but at a loss for what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Newer Macs can't run older OSX.

A 2012 iMac will run a Mountain Lion and upward.

Comment: All this just to run windows only medical info program!  Damn LifeScan...

Comment: Why would you need Snow Leopard to run Windows ? You can do a Bootcamp partion or use a Virtual Machine. Both solution are available on Mavericks !

Comment: Nothing forward of SL allows for XP which is the last Windows I invested in.  I refuse to buy any more of their disks.  VirtualBox works but LifeScan software doesn't connect from within.